# How to extract image data correctly with List Comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, jpeg

I have a simple JPEG with only the numbers 9, 8, ....0, stored in it. The dimensions are 28 x 280.

Believing that the images in the jpeg go left to right, then my 10 images would be 28 x 28 each (10 x 28 = 280).

The list comprehension I'm using to get the integer values from the image is this:

`image_parts = [image_1[:, k:k + 28] for k in range(10)]`

This indeed gives me 10 array elements, but they all seem to be the '9' character.

The code I used to try to get a middle value was this:

```
test_img = np.array(image_parts_1[5]).reshape(28,28)
```

but that displays a '9' also.

So, my list comprehension is wrong, the way I'm trying to extract the value is wrong, or my assumption about how the jpeg is ordered (left to right) is wrong. Or some combination (or something else).

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello. I'm a little worried about how you're reading the JPEG data. Unlike raw image files JPEGs are subject to lossy compression, you can't read the file block by block and expect to replicate the image verbatim: please note [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_compression). However, if you can provide an example of how you've read the image into your array, I'd be happy to help answer your question... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your list comprehension is wrong. Try `image_parts = [image_1[:, k * 28:(k + 1) * 28] for k in range(10)]`

Comment: Thanks, but your list comprehension doesn't work at all. My list comprehension in the original posting does create 10 array elements. Just not sure what's wrong. Thanks for your suggestion in any case.